# Adding base price in minicart - Magento 2.4.6 + hyva theme

Tags: price, hyva, base

I've been looking for a solution for some time to add the base price to the hyva minicart (the one reworked with alpineJS), not the already discounted one.

Do you have an idea on how to do it?

Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect, and go to total information. All values are calculated like this.

Replace grand_total with base_grand_total in checkout/cart and checkout order summary.

So you have to replace getValue() with getBaseValue() in your  files.

```
<tr class="last"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="grand totals">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: title"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getBaseValue()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html

[image]